# Проблема с установкой библиотеки pyproj

Tags: python

Кто ставил эту библиотеку в Python? Я пробую в Пайчарме через pip install . В результате мне выдает:  "... Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: using bundled proj4....."
По ссылке https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj в разделе "Installation" есть рекомендации, но я пока не понимаю. Может кто разжует?

Answer (score 1):

1. Скачать исходник.
2. В папке открыть терминал и ввести: `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`
3. Открыть в текстовом редакторе ***_proj.pyx*** и в первую строчку добавить:

   `# cython: linetrace=True`
4. Назад в терминал:

   *Unix*: `export PYPROJ_FULL_COVERGAGE=1`

   *Windows*: `set PYPROJ_FULL_COVERGAGE=1`
5. Выполняем:

`python setup.py build_ext --inplace` и 
`python setup.py install`

После этого все должно установиться.

Comment: При выполнении п.5  все равно пишет "using bundled proj4......" .  Правда теперь без строки "Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:"

Comment: @Rashid-s Можете предоставить вывод полностью? На pastebin залейте и скиньте сюда.

Comment: Все получилось. Вот ссылка на мой вопрос в гитхабе https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/116

Comment: @Rashid-s А ларчик просто открывался =)

Comment: Да, эт точно )))